# getting checked checkbox values and form input value using jquery ajax submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm implementing an appilication in which one module contains search method, we get the list of people in table, here is the code for it.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="sample_3">
  <div class="modal fade" id="sms" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Compose Sms</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="smsmessage"></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn blue">Send Sms</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
  </div>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_3 .checkboxes"/></th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Town</th>
      <th>Mobile No</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php 
  if($numrows!= "0") {
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
?>

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="<?php echo $result['mobileNo'];?>" name="numbers"/></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['surname']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['sex']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['preTown']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $result['mobileNo']; ?></td>
      <td><a href="details.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs green"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> View</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="editdetails.php?id=<?php echo $result['id'];?>" class="btn btn-xs blue"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp<a class="fancybox-button fancybox.iframe btn btn-xs purple" href="singlesms.php?number=<?php echo $result['mobileNo'];?>"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Send Sms</a></td>
    </tr>

<?php 
    }
  } else { 
?>

    <tr>
      <td>No Records Found</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

<?php
  }
?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

now if i click submit button, i want only those values to be sent which are selected by checkbox. i want the checkbox values and input:smsmessage to be sent through jquery ajax submit. i have implemented a code but it just uses the checkbox values, i want the input value to be passed through ajax post. here is the what i have implemented

```
    $('.btnadd').click(function(){
        var checkValues = $('input[name=numbers]:checked').map(function()
        {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'loadmore.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { ids: checkValues },
            success:function(data){

            }
        });
    });
```

Can u please suggest how to send the input:smsmessage also to this post method.
here is the bulksms.php

```
          $success="0";
           $message=$_POST['smsmessage'];
         if($message="")
          {
              echo "Please Provide Details Correctly";
           }
           foreach($number as $_POST['numbers'])
               {

$parameters['mobilenumber']=$number;
$parameters['message'] = $message;
            if(api_connect("demo","demo@123",$parameters))
                {
                    $success="1";
                }

               }
         if($success=="1")
                  {
         echo "SMS Sent to all selected people";
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at pushing the value onto the end of the `checkValues` array, like this:

```
$('.btnadd').click(function(){
    var checkValues = $('input[name=numbers]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    checkValues.push( $('input[name=smsmessage]').val() );

    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { ids: checkValues },
        success:function(data){ }
    });
});
```

Or you could add another data value in the ajax call:

```
$('.btnadd').click(function(){
    var checkValues = $('input[name=numbers]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { ids: checkValues, smsmessage: $('input[name=smsmessage]').val() },
        success:function(data){ }
    });
});
```

---

```
  $('.btnadd').click(function(){
        checked = $('input[name=numbers]:checked');
        if( checked.length > 0 ) {
            var checkValues = checked.map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'loadmore.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: { ids: checkValues },
                success:function(data){ }
            });
        }else{
             alert("You need to pick at least one checkbox!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: giving a try just wait for few minutes

Comment: Please post bulksms.php file contents

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: smsmessage
Notice: Undefined variable: number
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 

in this lines

   $success="0";
   $message=$_POST['smsmessage'];
   if($message="")
   {
    echo "Please Provide Details Correctly";
   }
   foreach($number as $_POST['numbers'])
   {
 
 $parameters['mobilenumber']=$number;
 $parameters['message'] = $message;

Comment: Can you add it to your question? It would be better to see the code formatted correctly :)

Comment: Hmm thanks for update - I have several questions: In your `foreach` loop, you're referencing `$number` and `$_POST['numbers']` - where are either of these defined? Secondly, the `undefined variable` error is coming from `$_POST['smsmessage']` - is there any way you could create an alert before the `ajax` call to see the contents of the `data` object is being sent?

Comment: i am thinking that $_post['numbers'] are coming from 
        data: { numbers: checkValues, smsmessage: $('input[name=smsmessage]').val() } and for smsmessage i have solved the issue by taking the textarea value

Comment: How did you take the textarea value? Btw your code had `data: { ids: checkValues }`, that's what confused me! ;)

Comment: i have change data:{ids: checkValues} to 
      data: { numbers: checkValues, smsmessage: $('.smsmessage').val()  },

Comment: and i have given class="smsmessage" to textarea

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() ERROR

Comment: lol okay so it's still not working! Can you put an alert before your `ajax` call so you can see all the values being sent?

Comment: i think this foreach($number as $_POST['numbers']) should be   foreach($_POST['numbers'] as $number)

Comment: this is not giving me error but i'm getting only sms sent sent successfully message to all even if the function fails

Comment: We need to check to see if the problem is with the PHP or the Ajax call - did you try the alert I mentioned?

Comment: i have returned the response from the api_connect function... its MESSAGE IS NOT PROVIDED. i think bulksms is not getting the smsmessage value

Comment: You can check that with the alert method I mentioned -- before the ajax call, alert the smsmessage value to see if it's being populated. If so, then you have a problem with PHP, if not, the problem is with JS

Comment: Rich Now its working.. i need a favour from you, i just want some validation such as if none check box are checked then user to be alerted