# bootstrap checkbox values on submit

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap in an PHP web application. I use the issues to generate a form, and include some checkbox's in the form, like this

```
//PHP Code To Generate the CheckBox
echo '<input id="myCheckBox" name="myCheckBox" type="checkbox" requiered value="1">';
```

Then, I manange the submit of the form manually, with ajax, and do something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: { $("#myCheckBox").val()},
            url: 'someurl.php',
            success: function () { alert('Something to do')} 
});
```

The problem is when I recover the content of $_POST variables on PHP. The POST variable of the checkbox always contains 'on' as value.

Any help to get the value of this CheckBox using this way?

Thanks!.

Comment: `data` is not a valid JavaScript object.

Comment: Data is a valid option, but not how OP did it in this case

Comment: `requiered` is a typo btw. Do `required`.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard No it is not. `data` is a valid _property_ for the object you pass as a parameter to `$.ajax` but the value OP is assigning to it is not a valid JS _object_ and actually results in a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clearing up what you meant @SergiuParaschiv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `data: { $("#myCheckBox").val()},` is not valid.

Try this:

```
var checkValues = $('input[name=myCheckBox]:checked').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).get();

$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   data: { 'checkbox': checkValues },
   url: 'someurl.php',
   success: function () { alert('Something to do')} 
});
```

As seen in: [getting checked checkbox values and form input value using jquery ajax submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718314/getting-checked-checkbox-values-and-form-input-value-using-jquery-ajax-submit)

More info also here: [How to get the values of all checked checkboxes using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474729/how-to-get-all-the-values-of-the-checked-checkboxes-using-jquery-checkboxes-is)

Comment: With this I received if checkbox was checked 1, and is not was checked 0?

Comment: Or I have to implement a function or something, that I give the selector or the name of checkbox to build the selector and return 0 or 1, checked or not checked?... Thanks again!...

Comment: 0 or 1 is just true or false. A common return value for checkboxes.